# Need help on how to convert PHP code from object to procedural?

Tags: php, mysql

I was hoping someone can help me convert this piece of code from object form to procedural form.

So I can have a sense of what to do for when I try to convert the larger piece of code that is all in object form that this snippet came from.

I'm a brand new beginner.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, label, link_url, parent_id FROM dyn_menu ORDER BY parent_id, id ASC";
$items = mysql_query($sql);
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($items)) {
    if ($obj->parent_id == 0) {
        $parent_menu[$obj->id]['label'] = $obj->label;
        $parent_menu[$obj->id]['link'] = $obj->link_url;
    } else {
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['parent'] = $obj->parent_id;
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['label'] = $obj->label;
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['link'] = $obj->link_url;
        $parent_menu[$obj->parent_id]['count']++;
    }
}
mysql_free_result($items);
```

I know there is something wrong with this code?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id, label, link_url, parent_id FROM dyn_menu ORDER BY parent_id, id ASC");

if (!$dbc) {
    // There was an error...do something about it here...
    print mysqli_error();
}

while ($obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbc)) {
    if ($obj->parent_id == 0) {
        $parent_menu $obj['id']['label'] = $obj['label'];
        $parent_menu $obj['id']['link'] = $obj['link_url'];
    } else {
        $sub_menu $obj['id']['parent'] = $obj['parent_id'];
        $sub_menu $obj['id']['label'] = $obj['label'];
        $sub_menu $obj['id']['link'] = $obj['link_url'];
        $parent_menu $obj['parent_id']['count']++;
    }
}
mysql_free_result($dbc);
```

Comment: Don't do this just for the sake of doing it.

Comment: What you have is a clean approach, why change it?

Comment: Why not it would be very helpful.

Comment: everything else I have is in procedural.

Comment: I'd like to hear why you want to do this.  Just curious...  ("Because I want to learn xxxx" or "Because I want to see if I can do it" are perfectly acceptable answers...).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not at all sure what you're trying to accomplish. Instead of `mysql_fetch_object`, you want to use something else? [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) and [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) are largely similar. Instead of `$obj->id`, you'd write `$obj['id']`.

As for using `mysql_result` (fetching data one column at a time, by column number), it is supposedly much slower. I can't really think of a good reason to use it.

**Update**:
Your second code snippet uses a mix of three different ways to access MySQL: mysqli object style, mysqli procedural style, and the 'old' mysql extension (mysql_* functions). That is is not going to work.

There are some decent examples on this [PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). They show both the object oriented and "procedural" style.